# Simplifying the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_i\cdot x_j$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, summation, vectors

How can I simplify the expression $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_i\cdot x_j$?

$x$ is a vector of numbers of length $n$, and I am trying to prove that the result of the expression above is positive for any $x$ vector.  Is it equal to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_j$? If it is then my problem is solved, because $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2$ is non-negative (positive or zero).

Comment: Can you simplify just $\sum_{j=1}^n x_i\cdot x_j$, where $i$ is fixed?

Comment: I am trying to prove that the result of the expression abouve is positive for any x vector.

Comment: Does it equal to $ \sum _{i=1}^n x_{i} \cdot \sum _{j=1}^n x_{j} $ ? If it IS then my problem is solved :) Because $ (\sum _{i=1}^n x_{i} )^2 $ is always positive

Comment: @Сергій: Yes. Let $a=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(x_ix_j)= \sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^nax_i=a^2\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Your comment seems to answer the the question. Why not copy it to an answer... Meta: [What should one do when one's question has been answered in the comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments)

Comment: @Сергій We know that $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\ge0$ but not necessarily $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2>0$. (I would be careful about distinction between the words positive and non-negative.)

Comment: @Martin: Done. $\,$

Comment: @Martin, you are right, just a mistake. Non-negative is what I need :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_i x_j=\left(\sum_{i=1}^ nx_i\right)^2\;.$$

To see this, let $a=\sum_{i=1}^ nx_i$; then

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_i x_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^na x_i=a^2\;.$$